# Vertical Aligning CSS Grid Items

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am making my site's header mobile friendly using CSS grid. I searched for a way to align one of my columns vertically to the middle. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50064710/vertical-align-and-css-grid-relationship) answered that by making the column `display: flex`, but introduced a problem where when I hover over the link inside of the box, the box resizes and moves the text inside.

My Code:

```css
h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: garamond;
  font-size: 3vw;
  width: 90%;
  line-height: 5%;
}
header {
  background-color: darkred;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
.Logo-Master {
  width: 15vw;
  margin: 1em;
}
header h1 {
  color: white;
}
#newsCenter {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1vw;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#newsCenter p a {
  color: white;
  font-size: .9vw;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#newsCenter p a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.newsCenterValues {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<header style="display: grid; grid-template-rows: auto auto;">
  <div style="display: inline-grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr">
  <a href="../index.html"><img class="Logo-Master" src="https://static.nationalgeographic.co.uk/files/styles/image_3200/public/01-lion-populations-nationalgeographic_1777804.jpg?w=1600&h=900" alt="This is an image"></a>
  <div>
    <h1>Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;"><div id="newsCenter">
    <p style="font-size: 1.2rem; font-weight: bold; color: white; line-height: 0;">Flex</p>
    <p class="newsCenterValues" style="line-height: 0;"><a href="#">The Long Link that in this section</a></p>
  </div></div>
  </div>
</header>
```

The text within the flex column is supposed to be `text-align: center;` but it is not behaving like that. How can I fix this with it still becoming bold when I hover over it?

Comment: I'm unsure of the issue. The only thing I see happening is that the link gets bigger when you hover over it.

Comment: he essence of your problem is not entirely clear.

Comment: The problem is that the link gets bigger (because it becomes bold), but the entire contents of the flexbox are moved over to the side slightly which should not be happening.

Comment: Hi Vtex, you are changing font weight of link on hover. That is the reason link gets bigger on hover

Comment: Try some solutions from this https://css-tricks.com/bold-on-hover-without-the-layout-shift/

Comment: That is the reason it gets bigger, but I do not want it to move the contents of the box.

Comment: Added a style *justify-content: center* to the parent DIV of #newsCenter. I hope got the solution.@Vtex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: garamond;
  font-size: 3vw;
  width: 90%;
  line-height: 5%;
}
header {
  background-color: darkred;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
.Logo-Master {
  width: 15vw;
  margin: 1em;
}
header h1 {
  color: white;
}
#newsCenter {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1vw;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#newsCenter p a {
  color: white;
  font-size: .9vw;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#newsCenter p a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.newsCenterValues {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<header style="display: grid; grid-template-rows: auto auto;">
  <div style="display: inline-grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr">
  <a href="../index.html"><img class="Logo-Master" src="https://static.nationalgeographic.co.uk/files/styles/image_3200/public/01-lion-populations-nationalgeographic_1777804.jpg?w=1600&h=900" alt="This is an image"></a>
  <div>
    <h1>Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;justify-content: center;"><div id="newsCenter">
    <p style="font-size: 1.2rem; font-weight: bold; color: white; line-height: 0;">Flex</p>
    <p class="newsCenterValues" style="line-height: 0;"><a href="#">The Long Link that in this section</a></p>
  </div></div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Is this expected..?

Answer (score 0):

This will not shift the content. In this example, I used `transform: scale()`.

```css
h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: garamond;
  font-size: 3vw;
  width: 90%;
  line-height: 5%;
}
header {
  background-color: darkred;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
.Logo-Master {
  width: 15vw;
  margin: 1em;
}
header h1 {
  color: white;
}
#newsCenter {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1vw;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: .2s;
}
#newsCenter p a {
  color: white;
  font-size: .9vw;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#newsCenter:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.newsCenterValues {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<header style="display: grid; grid-template-rows: auto auto;">
  <div style="display: inline-grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr">
  <a href="../index.html"><img class="Logo-Master" src="https://static.nationalgeographic.co.uk/files/styles/image_3200/public/01-lion-populations-nationalgeographic_1777804.jpg?w=1600&h=900" alt="This is an image"></a>
  <div>
    <h1>Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;"><div id="newsCenter">
    <p style="font-size: 1.2rem; font-weight: bold; color: white; line-height: 0;">Flex</p>
    <p class="newsCenterValues" style="line-height: 0;"><a href="#">The Long Link that in this section</a></p>
  </div></div>
  </div>
</header>
```